# What to do when expectation maximization results are invalid (they don't match the likert scale)

Tags: missing-data, expectation-maximization, errors-in-variables, mcar

I have missing values (MCAR) for which I used EM to fill in those values. Some of the imputed values are negative integers or zero.  I am using a likert scale to measure responses, and thus i need the missing values to equal between 1 and 5.

To deal with this problem i re-coded my data table in SPSS so that likert scale runs from 0 to 4, this way if the obtained missing value equals zero I can use it.  However this does not solve the negative integers.  Is it possible to put a restriction on the results so that they don't come up as negative?

Any suggestions, or references to a book/article about this?

Thanks.

Update:  to anyone sharing this problem, this may be helpful:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21478542

Comment: EM should return a maximum argument for the imputed values, argument taken over the range of possible values, hence you can restrict the imputed values to be in any set you want them to be.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Do you have advice as to how I can do this in SPSS?

Comment: Not at all. This is not the primary purpose of this forum.